# How to limit onSwiped() to ignore in one direction?

Tags: android

I have a onSwiped() that does what necessary when swiped to the right and not to the left, the problem is that it still swipes and I want it to "freeze" when swiped to the left.

```
 ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END,
                ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END) {
                @Override
                 public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                Log.d(TAG, "whats swiped " + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + "   direction: " + direction + "   arrayListCountyNames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())" + arrayListCountyNames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                if (direction==16) {//do something}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `ItemTouchHepler.RIGHT` as second param when create `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`:

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END,
            ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT));
```